# Tkinter Frame background disappear when I associate a Label to it

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a GUI in **Tkinter**. But when I associate a **Label** in any **Frame**, its background color disappers. Whereas, I expect this the whole background of the label to be green.

My code is pasted below

```
from Tkinter import *
from time import *

root = Tk()
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

leftFrame = Frame(root, width = 200, height = 200, bg = 'green')
leftFrame.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

centerFrame = Frame(root, width = 200, height = 200, bg = 'black')
centerFrame.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

rightFrame = Frame(root, width = 200, height = 200, bg = 'blue')
rightFrame.grid(row = 1, column = 3) 

b = Label(leftFrame, text = "Press me!", bg = 'green')
b.pack(side = TOP, expand = YES)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frames typically "shrink to fit" their contents unless there's a constraint put on the frame. This is normal, expected, and usually desirable. So, the left frame will request that it is just wide enough to fit the label, and just tall enough to fit the label. The frames in the other columns, because they have no children, will be the size that you request.

So, you have one column that wants to be as wide and as tall as the label, and two other columns that want to be 200 pixels wide. You have one row that wants to be tall enough to fit everything, which means it is as tall as the tallest widget, or 200 pixels. This ends up leaving extra space in the leftmost column.

Without specifying any options, each row will be as tall as the tallest widget in the row, in this case 200 pixels. Each column will be as wide as the widest widget. The leftmost column wants to be the width of the frame, which itself wants to be only as wide as the label. So, the leftmost column will be only as wide as the label. The other columns will be 200 pixels wide because that's what you told them to be.

Now, you want the green frame to fill the cell that it is in. In your case you haven't asked that the frame fill the space allotted so it shrinks to fit. You need to add the `sticky` option to the frame to force it to "stick" to all four edges of the space it was given.

```
leftFrame.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
```

Of course, you'll have the same problems with the other frames as well, assuming you plan to put widgets in them.

Comment: Thanks, but there is still one issue. This expands the frame in vertical direction but doesn't expand horizontally in span of 200.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Your question mentions nothng about a span.

Comment: I mean the width of the leftFrame remains equal to width of Label. Only the height changes by adding "nsew" option.

Comment: Can you once try the code in your system and explain?

Comment: @Rusty: Again, the left column is only as wide as the label because the frame "shrinks to fit". The reason it "grows" in the vertical direction is because there's extra space in the table cell that has the label. By specifying the sticky option, the frame expands to fill that extra space. There is no extra space in the horizontal direction, so the column is only as wide as the label. The other columns are wider because you tell the frames to be wider, and the grid will try to display each column so that it's widest child is fully visible.

Comment: Can you suggest me the way out? I want all three frames to be equally sized.

Comment: That's a different question than the one you asked. You asked why the background disappears. I can't give you a proper answer in a comment, though I recommend you read documentation on the "uniform" option to `grid_columnconfigure`.

Answer (score 0):

The actual frame size is the same as the widget it contains, so everything green is the frame.  Everything else is just filler to make it the same size as the other frames.  To have the frame fill the entire space available use "nsew"

Whoops,  already answered below.  I don't know why you are importing time but it is not a good idea to use time in a Tkinter environment.  Use the builtin "after" instead http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

leftFrame = Frame(root, width = 200, height = 200, bg = 'green')
leftFrame.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky="nesw")

centerFrame = Frame(root, width = 200, height = 200, bg = 'black')
centerFrame.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

rightFrame = Frame(root, width = 200, height = 200, bg = 'blue')
rightFrame.grid(row = 1, column = 3) 

b = Label(leftFrame, text = "Press me!", bg = 'green')
b.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is still one issue. This expands the frame in vertical direction but doesn't expand horizontally in span of 200.