# A Tkinter Frame is instantiated with super(). Why can I not make a Label widget its child?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

This concerns Python and Tkinter.

1. I wish to have a Label widget display the word "Meow".
2. The Label widget should be the *child of a Frame* in a Tk window.

This seems simple, yet the code below does not work - nothing appears:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Options(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, gui_parent):

        super().__init__()
        tk.Label(self, text="Meow").pack()

class Gui(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        Options(self)

gui = Gui()
gui.mainloop()
```

I then experimented: if I change the Label widget to `tk.Label(gui_parent, text="Meow").pack()`, the content of the window then appears. (However this is not the 'correct' behaviour, since I wish for the Label widget to be a direct child of the Frame widget, not of the Tk parent window.)

To my understanding, `super().__init__()` should have instantiated a Frame. The Label widget should then be able to access the Frame via `self`. This is not so.

Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not `pack` your `Options` widget. Try with:

```
Options(self).pack()
```

Also, I would explicitly state that `Options` is the child of `Gui`, so you should pass `gui_parent` to the `__init__` function of `Options` objects:

```
def __init__(self, gui_parent):
    super().__init__(gui_parent)
    tk.Label(self, text="Meow").pack()
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not know that had to be packed, or the gui_parent in `init`. One further question: how do I modify the instantiated Frame's background colour? I tried changing it to `super().__init__(background='red')` and `super().__init__(bg='red')`, and I even tried `self.config(background='red')` but none of them work. The idea is to have "Meow" on a red background.

Comment: @anonnoir: Sorry, I don't really know. Try to look at the following questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413459/adding-label-to-frame-in-tkinter-ignores-the-attributes-of-frame, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27633545/tkinter-frame-background-disappear-when-i-associate-a-label-to-it, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639125/how-do-i-change-the-background-of-a-frame-in-tkinter.

Comment: I improvised off the answers for some of those questions, particularly this one -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11414185/283169. It then worked. Thank you for the guidance!